# How can write a CSS style for a parent class?

Tags: css

I hope to write a css styple for the parent class of `<a class="Undo" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Undo"></a>`
but I don't know how to do, I'm a beginner of CSS styple.
I know, "#MyTools ul li" are for all li, now I hope to write a css for the one li which have child `<a class="Undo" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Undo"></a>`

```
#MyTools ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
}

#MyTools ul li a.Copy{ background-position: 0 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; } 
#MyTools ul li a.Cut{ background-position: -20px 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; } 
#MyTools ul li a.Paste{ background-position: -40px 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; } 
#MyTools ul li a.Redo{ background-position: -60px 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; } 
#MyTools ul li a.Undo{ background-position: -80px 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; } 


<div id="MyTools">
<ul>
<li>
<a class="Undo" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Undo"></a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="Redo" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Redo"></a>
</li>
<li class="separator"></li>
<li>
<a class="Cut" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Cut"></a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no parent selector. You can, however attach a class name to the parent, and assign CSS properties to that class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with CSS. You can with jQuery though:
http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Or with plain JS by checking boolean truth of `yourParentElement.querySelector('A.undo')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the div:

```
#myTools { /* ... */ }
```

If you want to style the ul:

```
#myTools ul { /* ... */ }
```

Unfortunately there's no parent selector in CSS (not even CSS3), so if there's something above `#myTools` that you need to style you'll need to figure out how to write the appropriate top down selector (or assign a new class/id to the element).

Comment: If I use JQuery, how can select the object which have child object <a class="Undo" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Undo"></a> ?